# How to set an environment variable on a server with puppet?

Tags: ruby, jruby, environment-variables, production-environment, puppet

I'm starting to use puppet in my current project and I'm having some issues.

I'm using a recipe to install jruby, but I want to set a environment variable (in this case, JRUBY_HOME and modify the PATH to include JRUBY_HOME/bin) after it finishes installing jruby.

Here's the recipe:

```
class jruby {
  $jruby_home = "/opt/jruby"


  exec { "download_jruby":
    command => "wget http://jruby.org.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/1.7.0.RC2/jruby-bin-1.7.0.RC2.tar.gz",
    path => $path,    
    timeout => 0,
    unless => "ls /opt | grep jruby-1.7.0",
    require => Package["openjdk-7-jre-headless"]
  }                

  exec { "unpack_jruby" :
    command => "tar -zxf jruby-bin-1.7.0.RC2.tar.gz -C /opt",
    path => $path,
    creates => "${jruby_home}-1.7.0.RC2",
    require => Exec["download_jruby"]
  }                             

  file { $jruby_home:
    ensure => link,
    target => "${jruby_home}-1.7.0.RC2",
    require => Exec["unpack_jruby"]
  }                          

}
```

So, what's the best way to add /opt/jruby as JRUBY_HOME and then add JRUBY_HOME/bin to PATH?

Comment: For whom do you want this environment variable set?  All users or a particular application user?  Also, what operating system is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it:

```
# init.pp
$jruby_sh = "/etc/profile.d/jruby.sh"
file { $jruby_sh:
  ensure => present,
  source => "puppet:///modules/jruby/jruby.sh",
  owner => "root",
  group => "root",
  mode => 644,
  require => File[$jruby_home]
}

# jruby.sh
export JRUBY_HOME=/opt/jruby
export PATH=$PATH:$JRUBY_HOME/bin
```